# Refresh Image - C# WPF

Tags: c#

Good evening:
I have a Listview that contains the Areas of a Place (Code and Description)
When I cross it, the fields Textbox, CheckBox and Image, "binding" perfectly. 
When I edit and record without touching the image, it works perfectly. 
My problem is in that when I Load a new image and I record, all the records (Areas) show the same image. This problem is alone on having showed because when I go out and enter to the application the values of the fields Image (SQL) they do not alter.

My code:

**XAML:**

```
        <Image x:Name="ImgFoto" Source="{Binding Foto}" Stretch="Fill"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181"
               Margin="243,371,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

**C#:**

Load Image (Foto):

```
   private void BtnCargarFoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OD = new OpenFileDialog();
        OD.Filter = "jpg(*.jpg)|*.jpg|png(*.png)|*.png|gif(*.gif)|*.gif|bmp(*.bmp)|*.bmp|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (OD.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (Stream stream = OD.OpenFile())
            {
                bitCoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                    BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                ImgFoto.Source = bitCoder.Frames[0];
            }
            System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(OD.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            foto = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length.ToString())];
            fs.Read(foto, 0, foto.Length);

        }
    }
```

The load works perfectly. 
What will be happening?????? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in English

Comment: 你问什么不清楚 **:)** ......(Hoping google translate works well )

Comment: Sorry. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines I think the problem is that you are overriding ImgFoto's Source databinding when you explicitly set the Source in BtnCargarFoto_Click. Instead of setting ImgFoto.Source to bitCoder.Frames[0] you should set the Foto property on the object that ImgFoto is bound to.

Comment: Thank you Rob.Then, how should my code stay finally? Thank you again.

Comment: I don´t understand when you say: "you should set the Foto property on the object that ImgFoto is bound to."..  Where do I do it?

Comment: The problem is that when I change the value of Image.Source to load a new image, the image is the same for all other records. Is there any way to refresh the Image control? 
I have to exit and re enter the application to correctly display the image. 
Thank you again.